# How do I search for a particular string in Linux?

Tags: vasp, high-performance-computing

I want to search for a value in the VASP `OUTCAR` file i.e the format of the line should be

```
 Volume of Typ   1:     98.5 %
```

What command line should I type in `OUTCAR` to go for a specific line or word?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the command grep? https://phoenixnap.com/kb/grep-command-linux-unix-examples

Comment: Yes, grep is the way to go. For your case that would be: grep 'Volume of' OUTCAR

Comment: In the future, I would search StackOverflow (or for this particular example, Unix/Linux SE) first for questions that are about general programming (or general tools in Linux). [Answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503527/search-all-occurrences-of-string-in-linux), [Answer on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333121/how-to-find-lines-containing-a-string-and-then-printing-those-specific-lines-and)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about a basic operation in Linux environment and has nothing to do with Matter Modeling.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer The close request was rejected early by a moderator: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/review/close/1129. The question already has an answer, and in 60 days the community couldn't think of any reason why a question about post-processing matter modeling calculations should be closed if it got decent answers already: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222/if-a-question-already-has-a-good-answer-does-it-need-to-be-closed#comment453_228. I agree the user might have got better answers if they asked at LinuxUnix.SE but they asked & got good answers here!

Comment: Out of 1000+ questions, this is the only "pure" Linux question we have, so I don't see this type of thing as a big systemic problem: it's more of a "rare idiosyncrasy". We could try to migrate, but then we have to choose whether to migrate to AskUbuntu, LinuxUnix, SuperUser, SO, etc. I think questions about how to run MM jobs (https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/862/5, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1570/5), choosing hardware (https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/883/5, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2112/5) or pre- or post-processing MM calculations is ok!

Comment: As I see it, the most difficult part is all about asking the right question. The OP's problem is to dig out a specific portion of the VASP output. The right place to ask that question is definitely MMSE. Incidentally it can be argued that the solution belong to someother SE

Answer (score 15):

The `OUTCAR` is a text file. Therefore, you can use the `grep` command to grab what you want to search for.

- Print the current line:

  ```
  grep  "key_information_string" OUTCAR
  ```
- Print more lines below the current line:

  ```
  grep  "key_information_string" OUTCAR -A n
  ```
- Print more lines above the current line:

  ```
  grep  "key_information_string" OUTCAR -B n
  ```

Here $n$ represents the number of lines you want to print, such as 5.

Comment: +1. I've given more examples of using `grep` here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2416/5

Comment: I think it's worth explaining that `n` is to be substituted with the number of lines.

Comment: @Ruslan I have added that.

Comment: I think that this answer might be improved by a reference to regex to search an entire document for specific lines.

Comment: @nick012000 why not add am answer! We're all waiting for you!

Comment: @NikeDattani Because regex is complicated, and I'm not confident enough in Linux to write an answer about it! ;)

Comment: At you service, @nick012000. (Someone appears to be having a bad day.)

Comment: There's a small miswording in the description of the -A and -B flags. The -A flag shows lines after the match, and -B shows lines before the match.

Comment: if you know a component/element of a string [grep] is the best function to use. and if you want to get a specific string you can use [grep] and [awk] as conjunction form to print out the desired string. e.g. grep 'PIECE OF STRINGS'  {path/to/the/file} | awk '{print $1, $2}'

Answer (score 14):

**Use `rg`**

If you have a significant size file or file(s) to search, do yourself a favor and choose one of the many significantly faster alternatives to `grep`, the de facto fastest being [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep).

**Specific values**

```bash
# literal string
rg <options> 'Volume of Typ   1:     98.5 %'     path/to/file/or/directory
```

```bash
# any value for the key
rg <options> 'Volume of Typ   1:'                path/to/file/or/directory
```

```bash
# any numeric value
rg <options> 'Volume of Typ   1:\s*\d+\.?\d*'    path/to/file/or/directory
```

```bash
# any numeric percentage
rg <options> 'Volume of Typ   1:\s*\d+\.?\d*\s%' path/to/file/or/directory
```

Where `<options>` are any additional parameters you want to pass (may be omitted).
The `path` argument may be omitted as well, it defaults to the current working directory.
Obviously, you could make the search parameter for the key a pattern too.

N.B. The syntax is the same for `grep` (or `ag`, or the like).

**Selection**

If you wanted to *select* the values only (as in strip the key and unit / suffix), `sed` is an option:

```bash
cat path/to/file | sed -en 's!^Volume of Typ\s*1:\s*\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*$!\1!gp'
```

At this point, you've got **a list of line-terminated, matched values** on your screen.
Neato, no more noise!

**Next**

Other than looking at the output on screen, you could:

- store it in another file `<previous_command> > path/to/values.csv`
- pipe it to the next command (e.g. to visualize the values):
  `<previous_command> | awk '{print NR " " $0}' | gnuplot -p -e "plot '<cat'"`
  (Exercise left to the avid reader: The extraction of the `Typ n` type number to plot on the x-axis, instead of the running index `NR`.)

Narrower conditions are obviously possible.

**Tips**

- Single quoted `'` strings make regexes in the shell significantly easier to type.
- Use a better delimiter for `sed` than the often cited `/`, `!` for instance.

**References**

- [`man rg`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rg&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)
- [`man sed`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1)
- [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [online regex debugger](https://regex101.com/)

**Bonus: `sed` breakdown**

```bash
cat path/to/file | sed -en 's!^Volume of Typ\s*1:\s*\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*$!\1!gp'
```

- `cat`<sup>1</sup> reads the file from disk and prints its contents to `stdout`
- `|` is a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix))
- `sed` is a **s**tream **ed**itor:

  - the `-e` flag isn't strictly necessary, it's just there to allow for possibly multiple "script" inputs at once
  - `-n` suppresses output (get rid of non-matching lines)
  - the script argument decodes as `s!<search_pattern>!<replacement>!<flags>`

    - wherein `<search_pattern>`

      - `^` beginning of the line
      - `Volume of Typ` literal string to be matched
      - `\s*` any number of whitespaces
      - `:` literal string to be matched
      - `\s*` any number of whitespaces
      - `(...)` group that may be referenced (no effect on matching)
      - `[0-9]*` any number of digits (character class with a `*` quantifier)
      - `\.` an escaped, literal period (`.` has a logical meaning in regular expressions)
    - wherein `<replacement>` is `\1`, a *backreference* to the group `(...)` above
    - wherein the `<flags>` are:

      - `g` apply globally (you want more than one match)
      - `p` print matches to `stdout` (we had negated *all* output with `-n` earlier to get rid of non-matching lines)

<sup>1</sup> For the sake of completeness: `cat`'s actual purpose is text (or file) con*cat*enation and it takes any number of arguments. Most of its invocations in its lifetime have certainly been with one argument to read a file.

Answer (score 3):

To search for all the strings in all of the files in current folder you would use simply:

```
grep string *
```

Or in subfolder:

```
grep string subfolder/*
```

Unfortunately recursion is not possible so you can only search one folder at the time.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you elaborate on what this adds that isn't included in the existing answers? Also, most newer versions of grep allow a recursive search by using the `-r` flag.

Comment: @Tyberius Answer from @Jack uses `grep` so that it targets a speciffic file, but you can target multiple files like I did here. I did not know about the recursion!? How can this be done? Can you give me an excakmple here in the comments?

Comment: If you do `grep -R "some string" ./`, it will search for "some string" in every file in every subdirectory of ./ . Using `-R`, rather than `-r`, even allows it to search through symbolic links. This is at least the case for GNU grep version 2.20.

Answer (score 3):

If you open with vim, you can find it by following command line.

vim OUTCAR and input '?Volume of Type' or '/Volume of Type', press n or N to find previous one next one with string 'Volume of Type'.